Regex matching in a Splunk search query that involves a lookup table
I have created a lookup table in Splunk that contains a column with various regex patterns intended to match file paths. My goal is to use this lookup table within a search query to identify events where the path field matches any of the regex patterns specified in the Regex_Path column.
The lookup table:

Here is the challenge I'm facing:
When using the match() function in my search query, it only successfully matches if the Regex_Path pattern completely matches the path field in the event. However, I expected match() to perform partial matches based on the regex pattern, which does not seem to be the case.
Interestingly, if I manually replace the Regex_Path in the where match() clause with the actual regex pattern, it successfully performs the match as expected.
Here is an example of my search query:
index=teleport event="sftp" path!=""
| eval path_lower=lower(path)
| lookup Sensitive_File_Path.csv Regex_Path AS path_lower OUTPUT Regex_Path, Note
| where match(path_lower, Regex_Path)
| table path_lower, Regex_Path, Note

I would like to understand why the match() function isn't working as anticipated when using the lookup table and whether there is a better method to achieve the desired regex matching.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
